# File upload restrictions per browser and environment

Tags: asp.net, iis, browser, file-upload

I am looking for the restrictions on file upload sizes per browser and environment to try and find my bottleneck. I've been told it's 2 gigs but I don't know where/what the limiting factor is. Specifically, I'm looking for the max size for each of the below:

- Firefox
- IE
- Chrome
- IIS 6
- IIS 7.5
- ASP.NET 4.0

Note: We are using native browser upload; no flash, java, or the like

Comment: I know the tubes are bigger these days but, uhm, is anyone going to wait for 2GB upload to complete? :-/ (Most default upload caps seem 2-10MB.)

Comment: It is HD video. The pipes here on our campus are pretty fast as well. Lastly, it is required for their course work. To sum it up then I guess, yes they will wait for it. :)

Comment: They will also know going into the process that it will be lengthy. It will not be just any users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would imaging the "2 gig limit" mentioned is a result of 32-bit integers (read: most 32-bit programs/servers) used throughout the various infrastructure -- it's only relatively recently that 64-bit file access has made it into consumer operating systems. (In addition to the above end-points, any intermediate proxies as well as file-systems, etc, must also be considered as limiting factors).

I can't find anywhere in [RFC 2616](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt) that actually sets the "upper limit" for things such as Content-Length though.

**Edit (my thoughts)**: If it's a captive audience, perhaps use an alternative (e.g. Flash/Silverlight/ActiveX/etc) agent for the uploads?

Comment: I agree about using Flash/Silverlight to do this. At the very least you'll be able to show a progress bar, and with a 2GB upload that's probably going to be pretty important, fast tubes or no.

Answer (score -1):

in asp.net web.config find tag `<httpRuntime >` or if it is not there add

```
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="...." ....
```

maxRequestLength limits how much is the request size. I think max value that can be set is 2G.